# PDF not opening in internet explorer browser in angularjs blob

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have an angular application that loads the stream in blob and displays in browser. I could use the below code to open in google chrome and firefox but not in internet explorer. I used the if condition as below, internet explorer not prompts for Open or Save. Is there a way, I can force the prompt to open directly. If there is any other code that supports showing the pdf in the browser is also appreciated.

My javascript code.

```
$http.post(apiURL + "/save", data, config)
.then(function (SuccessData) {
if (validateResponse(SuccessData.data, "Submit")) {
return;
}                    
$scope.Result = SuccessData.data;
data.CommissionId = SuccessData.data.CommissionId;
$http.post(apiURL + "/DownloadPdf", data, 
{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' }, config)
.then(function (result) {
var file = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileName = "CommissionStatement.pdf";
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {                             
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileName);                            
}
else {
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file, fileName);
window.open(objectUrl);
}   
});
},
function (error) {
$scope.Error = error.data;
});
```

this is my code behind from api
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, commissionId);
    var exportOptions = reportDocument.ExportOptions;
    exportOptions.ExportDestinationType =   ExportDestinationType.NoDestination;
    exportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
    var req = new ExportRequestContext { ExportInfo = exportOptions };
    var stream = reportDocument.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(req);

```
tempResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
tempResponse.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
tempResponse.Content.Headers.Add(@"Content-type", "application/pdf");
tempResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType =  new     System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue
("application/pdf");
tempResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new     System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add a mime type header?

Comment: Hi Reto, Please see my update on the code behind.. Thanks..

Comment: I could not find a solution in opening a blob inside Internet explorer yet. If you anyone has any idea, please let me know